# Why is it that a hard disk can have only 4 primary partitions?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of hard disk drive software partitions ?](https://superuser.com/questions/199956/meaning-of-hard-disk-drive-software-partitions)

What is the technical reason behind this? Also why can a hard disk can have only 1 extended partition.
Is there any limit to the number of logical partitions that can exist on an extended partition?

Comment: this question not relates here i think this should be moved to other SO sister sites ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record#Disk_partitioning .  Also this is off-topic :-)

Comment: You are talking about a particular partitioning scheme used by PCs with an age old BIOS. That does not apply to all computers. Anyway, this question may be better suited for Superuser.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind this is the same MBR that was used in **FLOPPY disks**.  I'll let you look up how big they are.

From there you can figure out why there are only four. . .

Comment: The boot record of a PC diskette does not have a partition table.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the default is 4. No one ever thought that anyone would need more than that.

But there is really a nearly unlimited number that can be made with a little tweaking. BootItNG, for example, can make more than 4 (not sure on upper limit).

Comment: Technically, the Extended partition can its own table. Thus the number of partition you can have inside the extended partition is theoretically limitless.  This pretty much how GUID works.

Comment: I think we are talking about primary partitions and not extended ones.