# Can I delete the OEM partition on the new Dell XPS 15?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dell-xps

My new Dell XPS 15 L521X just arrived.  I need to set this up to dual boot Linux.  Sadly, the system comes with four primary partitions.  I can't do a clean install at the moment, so one of the partitions will have to be deleted before I can install Linux.  The layout is as follows:

**OEM:**         39mb
**Hibernation:** 8gb
**OS:**          457gb
**Recovery:**    12gb

Obviously, I can't delete the Hibernation and OS partitions (will shrink to make space for Linux) and I'd like to keep the recovery partition if possible.  So my question is what is on the small OEM partition?  What functionality will I lose if I delete it?

Comment: Will 39MB even make a functional difference regarding your end goal?

Comment: It's not about the space. Apparently all four possible partitions are already used.

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/295604/5-primary-partitions, http://superuser.com/questions/199956/meaning-of-hard-disk-drive-software-partitions

Comment: Sadly, this question has been closed when it is not a duplicate and the links above do not answer my question.  The moderators are making assumptions about my needs because I added some context.  Please ignore the linux installation discussion.  I do not have any questions about primary vs extended partitions. My question is simply: "What is on the new Dell XPS OEM partition (39mb) and is it safe to delete?"  I think it just contains hardware diagnostics but I'm not sure.  Hopefully, the moderators will re-open the question.

Comment: To avoid such issues the moment I get a new laptop, the first that I do is delete all partitions and repartition the disk based on my requirements. Then reinstall the OS from the recovery disc that is provided with the laptop.

Comment: Trying to keep the Recovery partition is probably misguided.  The "recovery" procedures I've seen restore the disk to a factory-fresh state, and would only be used for extreme circumstances.  Also the contents of the Recovery partition can be burned to DVDs or CDs (using the manufacturer's utility) for full reinstallation. The Recovery partition is IMO the most expendable partition of the four.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That OEM partition you're looking at is most likely the [Dell Utility Partition](http://www.goodells.net/dellutility/). It essentially contains a diagnostic suite that you can access via the BIOS. It's not at all required for recovery or a factory restore, and you can download the same exact utilities from Dell's website and put them on a CD if you need them. Therefore, I'd say it's completely safe to delete it.

Comment: I'm uncertain that the Utility Partition is unused during recovery, but it's been a long time since I've had experience with Dell. I only mention as a caution and I'd recommend creating a full drive image as a backup before doing anything.

Comment: Thx guys ... this is exactly the kind of answer/discussion I'm looking for.

Comment: @jhayes The answer isn't meant to say the Utility Partition is not *useful* for recovery, or not *used by Dell* for recovery.  It's meant to say it's not *required* for recovery.  System recovery can be performed with third-party tools outside of the Utility Partition, just as well as (if not better than) with the tools that are pre-installed there.  The tools are just there to help facilitate end-user support - generally a moot issue for power users of the kind who would be installing multiple OS's.

Comment: Before deleting *any* partition, the OP should use a utility to determine which partition is marked as the *active* partition.  If this OEM partition is also MS's System Reserved partition, then he's in for a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - but make sure you use the tools to make recovery DVD or USB stick. I just recently got a XPS 8500 and did this after making the recovery stick, I wanted to boot from SSD so it was also a good time to verify the recovery stick made from the DELL utility would also install windows back to the default - it did.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to delete OEM partition because it contains your OS image file. You won't be able to reset your system back to the initial state after deleting the partition, so it's better to keep the partition.